# How to save all images in GraphicsGrid?

Tags: graphics, image

I have a 2X2 images. How to save all the images at once while using GraphicsGrid ? when I try the save graphic option  only one image is saved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Export`

```
gg = GraphicsGrid[Table[Plot[a*x^n, {x, 0, 1}], {n, 2}, {a, 2}]];

Export["test.jpg", gg];

Import["test.jpg"]
```

[image]

You can use other formats such as "test.gif" or "test.png"